# Total time of the loop

Tags: big-o

I have the following loop.I want to know the Total Time take bye each step of the loop the loop is given below and also my calculations please Check and correct me if I'm Wrong.

```
  int count=0;
   for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
     count++;
```

My calculations are the following.

```
Assginments operator is taking = 2
Comparison                     = N
Increments (i++ and Count++) = N+N =2N Times
```

so according to me its `3N+2` Please let me know If im wrong and please do tell me if in loop body is `count += 1;` How much time will be assigned to it.

Comment: Are you talking about *algorithmic complexity*?

Comment: Why all the language tags? If you're trying to find big-O it doesn't matter; it'll be O(N). You also don't need `i`.

Comment: "Assignments operator is taking = 2" *what*?  Nanoseconds?  Microseconds?  Shakes of a sheep's tail?  If you're trying to compute the time _complexity_, the answer will be something like O(N) meaning it's proportional to N, but the answer would not include the actual ratio (3) or an additional constant (2).  Those would have no place in the answer.

Comment: Always like to see people eager to do others' homework

Comment: @Borgleader it's not my homework.

Comment: What's that they say about assumptions? Something about an ass...

Comment: @ajb yes i remember the treacher calculated O(N) for this but he also said all this stuff i told above

Comment: It's work done at home -- thus it's home work.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: please don't. Your contributions here are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what your teacher was talking about.  Maybe they were counting "operations", using some arbitrary definition of what constitutes an "operation".  But that wouldn't help you compute the "total time", since not all operations take the same amount of time.  You can't even count on one *assignment* operation taking the same amount of time as another.

Answer (score 0):

**O(N)**

since runtime depends linearly on `N`.

And even `c*N` is still O(N). Its a rule that you can neglet the constant factor `c` in algorithm runtime complexity calculations. That means, it doesnt matter, if you have `2*N`, `5*N` or `247234*N`. Its always O(N).